# Issue with installing with wubi

Tags: installation, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu with wubi, dual booting with Windows XP. The installation is completed and the boot to Ubuntu is successful to the login screen. However, when I input the password, it takes me to a blank screen with only the wallpaper displayed. There is no menu, no left click menu either; there is nothing can be done at this stage. The only way to leave is through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

The boot to WinXP can be done as normal.

Please help advise what is the problem and how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the boot command. Add "nomodeset" (without quotes) (next to "splash")

To do this, open a console terminal (Ctrl Alt F1 as mentioned before).

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Navigate to the line that says
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (roughly Line 11)
3. Add `nomodeset`, next to `splash`. The line should now read:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, enter to save the file.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit
6. `sudo update-grub` to make the changes go into effect.
7. `sudo reboot now` to reboot the machine safely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get to command line. Then type this code:

```
sudo apt-get remove xorg
```

accept the two programs to be removed. Now type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope this help :D